# MongoDB php extension install on ubuntu 12.04: fatal error: Zend/zend_string.h: No such file or directory

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu, zend-framework

I've been trying to install a php 5.6 driver for mongodb on Ubuntu 12.04. (Will be using this on a Zend Framework 1.11 system, yes this is old, I am fully aware).

I've tried a few things, nothing works.

It seems I should get it to work using this installation:
http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.manual.php

But for some reason at the make all -j 5 step I get the following error:

In file included from /var/mongotest/mongo-php-driver/src/bson.c:29:0:
./phongo_compat.h:21:30: fatal error: Zend/zend_string.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from /var/mongotest/mongo-php-driver/src/bson-encode.c:29:0:
./phongo_compat.h:21:30: fatal error: Zend/zend_string.h: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install php5.6-dev, it includes all the header files.